# Clean URLs by turning view state off in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, viewstate

I have this long url, which I don't want:

```
 http://localhost:56563/TablesLibraryWebsite/searchresults.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTY3OTkxNDkxMWQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFI2N0bDAwJGNwaFJpZ2h0UGFuZWwka2V5d29yZFNlYXJjaEdP&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAgLoquEjAvXq39ML&type=search&keywords=Enter+keywords+%2F+publication+number&population=0&datasources=0&year=0&ctl00%24cphRightPanel%24keywordSearchGO.x=3&ctl00%24cphRightPanel%24keywordSearchGO.y=8
```

My form is declared like this:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="searchresults.aspx" id="searchform" 
    runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="search" />
    <div class="searchField">
        <input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywordSearch"
            name="keywordSearch" value="Enter keywords / publication number"
            class="watermark" />
    </div>
    <!--end searchField-->
    <div class="advanceSearchBox">
        <p><b>Narrow results by:</b></p>

        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlPopulation" runat="server" />                                
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlDatasource" runat="server" />                                 
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlYears" runat="server" />   

    </div>
    <!--end advanceSearchBox-->
    <div style="float: right; margin-right: 2px;">
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/go_up.png" AlternateText="GO" Width="34" 
            Height="24" id="keywordSearchGO" runat="server"
            EnableViewState="false" onclick="keywordSearchGO_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Why am I still getting this garbage?

My web.config also has pages enableviewstate="false" too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using GET as your form's method attribute. This will place the form value in URL as query strings. You should use "post" instead.

Comment: but i'm getting search results, so do a post anyway?

Comment: Yes. The main difference between GET and POST is how the data is made available to the page receiving the request.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that garbage because you declared the action method on the form as GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you enable viewstate? It will be stored in a hidden field else ASP.Net will do URL rewrite appending the viewstate.

Comment: oh so i'm doing it backwards?